# Error creating Azure Storage account using Terraform

Tags: azure-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm creating a storage account using Terraform v0.12.9 and provider.azurerm v1.34.0

Here is my code

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "platform" {

  name                     = "${var.name}"
  resource_group_name      = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  location                 = "${var.location}"
  account_kind             = "${var.account_kind}"
  account_tier             = "${var.account_tier}"
  account_replication_type = "${var.account_replication_type}"
  access_tier              = "${var.access_tier}"
  enable_blob_encryption   = "${var.enable_blob_encryption}"
  enable_file_encryption   = "${var.enable_file_encryption}"
  enable_https_traffic_only= "${var.enable_https_traffic_only}"

  tags = {
    environment = "test"
  }

  cors_rule = {
    allowed_headers   = ["*"]
    allowed_methods   = ["Get"]
    allowed_origins   = ["*"]
    exposed_headers   = ["*"]
    max_age_in_seconds= "1"
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error for cors_rule argument.

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 17, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "platform":
  17:   cors_rule = {

An argument named "cors_rule" is not expected here.
```

Even though it is specified in the documentation available here
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html#allowed_headers

Comment: Add Blob properties block like this:
  blob_properties {
    cors_rule {
      allowed_methods    = var.allowed_methods
      allowed_origins    = var.allowed_origins
      allowed_headers    = var.allowed_headers
      exposed_headers    = var.exposed_headers
      max_age_in_seconds = var.max_age_in_seconds
    }
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that the `cors_rule` block should be nested in the `queue_properties` block, but I agree, the documentation does not specify it clearly.

You can always check the provider on [github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/azurerm/resource_arm_storage_account.go#L269) to see the actual structure. I find this works better then looking at the documentation as the documentation can be confusing sometimes. Of course I then recommend creating a PR that makes the documentation clearer.